# C++ trouble with debuger

Tags: c++, debugging, ide, codelite

I'm trying out the CodeLite IDE for c++ programming.

Everything is OK except the debugger when I'm using the debugger to see what inside of a string, vector or even an object I can't see the value inside them.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rslDW.png)

Please help me with that.

Btw, I'm using minGW compiler.

Comment: Some classes of the std library are hard to understand about their inners. Expand the members until you find where the data is really stored.

Comment: Debugging release/optimized builds is *difficult*.

Comment: I guess you need an IDE with appropriate data visualization, such as Visual Studio or Eclipse.

Comment: @Ripi2 ahh ok, but what about the vector, I can't expand him..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the debugger pretty printing ON.
This can be checked from `Settings -> GDB Settings -> GNU gdb debugger -> Display`
and check the option:

`Enable GDB Pretty Printing`

If its already ON, then you are using a debugger without python support.

Attaching a screenshots to show how it should be looking.

[image]

[image]

HTH,
Eran

Comment: Thank you, Eran, for the answer, that option is already ON for me, what do you mean by python support?
How do I get it?

Comment: The pretty printing is coming from the debugger not from the IDE. Which debugger version do you use?